# AIR sqlite asynchronous database connection?

Tags: air

```
function openDatabase():void
{
    var dbFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("database.db");
    connection = new SQLConnection();
    connection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, onOpen);
    connection.openAsync(dbFile, "create");
}
```

i used this code in AIR to create connection and it's working but where is the database file??
where is the applicationStorageDirectory??

Answer (score 1):

It's platform dependent (Mac, Windows, etc.).  If you print out the value of "File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath", it will give you the fully-specified path on the filesystem of your current platform.